# ScriptDb: how to calculate the total of a field

Tags: database, google-apps-script

how can I calculate the sum of the value of a field?
I have this code but don't work.

```
 var db = dbAlpha.getDb(); 
     var results = db.query({TipoRecord: 'Alpha'});
    if (!results.getSize() == 0) {
  while (results.hasNext()) {
   var result = results.next();
   var Alpha = result.BudgetAlpha;
   var totalAlpha = totalAlpha + Alpha;
    }
   }
```

Thank you for help me.

raffaele

Answer (score 0):

Its not because of gas. Its because your js is incorrect. Look at th scoping in your totalAlpha which needs to be outside the loop.

Comment: Thank you Zig Mandel for your help. I found the solution: totalAlpha += parseFloat(result.BudgetAlpha);